# Angular 7 - [object Object] receiving as the output

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, stripe-payments

I have node backend with couple of endpoints related to stripe payment gateway. When I use POSTMAN to check the api call it works fine and give result. But I could not call it in angular service.ts and component.ts files. Please advice on this.

stripe.js - backend

```
router.get("/public-key", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    publicKey: "pk_test_123",
  });
});
```

stripe-script.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ScriptLoadingService } from './script-loading.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StripeScriptService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';
  private globalVar = 'stripe';
  private sessionId;
  constructor(private scriptLoadingService: ScriptLoadingService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPublicKey() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/stripe/public-key');
  }
}
```

stripe.component.ts

```
testStripe(): void {
    this.stripeScriptService.getPublicKey();
}
```

I receive the api call output as follows.
[image: Screenshot of postman result]

Comment: You did not show how your service was called in your component file.

Comment: Which port is using by your Angular application?

Comment: @Kerim localhost:4200

Comment: Maybe you should try with proxy server. Reference [here](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Comment: Could you please modify your function like this `getPublicKey(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>('http://localhost:3000/api/stripe/public-key');
  }`

Comment: It's because you did not subscribe to the result of `StripeScriptService#getPublicKey` in your component code.

Comment: where is the html that prints [object object]? upload it